# comparing local images swift

Tags: swift, image, if-statement, uiimage

"Optional type Bool cannot be used as a boolean; test for !nil instead"

Is the error I'm getting

I'm trying to make a "slot machine" app, very basic, 
You press the UIButton, and the three images should all change, randomly, if the 3 matches, print "You won!"

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var img1: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var img2: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var img3: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var rollBtn: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@IBAction func onRollPress(sender: AnyObject) {
    let randomRoll = ImgArray().getRandomImage()
     img1.image = randomRoll
     img2.image = randomRoll
     img3.image = randomRoll

    if (img1.image! == img2 && img3) {
        print("You won!")
    }

}

}
```

Comment: You should show us code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your images are in an array, why not get the indexes of the images and compare that.  Or you could convert the images to base64 strings and compare those.

**Edit:** Not knowing much about your ImgArray class, this may work for you:

```
@IBAction func onRollPress(sender: AnyObject) {
let randomRoll1 = ImgArray().getRandomImage()
let randomRoll2 = ImgArray().getRandomImage()
let randomRoll3 = ImgArray().getRandomImage()

img1.image = randomRoll1
img2.image = randomRoll2
img3.image = randomRoll3

let imgIndex1 = ImgArray().indexOf(randomRoll1)
let imgIndex2 = ImgArray().indexOf(randomRoll2)
let imgIndex3 = ImgArray().indexOf(randomRoll3)

if (imgIndex1 == imgIndex2 && imgIndex3) {
    print("You won!")
}
}
```

Comment: If I'm correct, if I were to use the indexes of my image array, I would not be able to compare them against the randomly generated image?

Comment: Is it truly a random image or are you picking images from an array randomly?

Comment: No you're right, I'm picking a random image from my array, but wouldn't I be comparing img1.image in this case, against a hard coded index number?

Comment: See my edit to the answer above... that may work for you.